# Print Preview To Show Only Content, and not Navigation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, printing

I have 2 content editor's which are placed at top left and top right. Top left is only for navigation while top right is for pure contents. When I click print preview, it also show navigation. I would like the print preview to only show pure contents (which is at top right), rather than showing navigation too.

How can I do this?

[image]

[image]

1st picture: Top left for navigation & top right for contents

2nd picture: Print preview mode where it also shows navigation.

I do not want it to show the navigation part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create separate `.css` for printing. In  `.css` file you have to include `@media print`.

```
@media print 
{
    #DeltaPageStatusBar,#sideNavBox,#DeltaFormDigest,#s4-titlerow,#notificationArea,#s4-ribbonrow,#ms-cui-topBar2,#ms-cui-ribbonTopBars,#suiteBar{
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

In comma separated class name also include the name of class applied to left column of page which shows the navigation.

To know more about `.css` for printing, you can refer [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) link.

Hope this helps.!!

Comment: it works but it hide the only top part of the page which is the icons, navigation and 'check in' banner. The navigation is still visible. I create a div in navigation, and display: none. It work but then it still have white space, without any navigation in that area.

Comment: I add #MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2, #WebPartWPQ2 for the left column. it works! thank you.